# how to draw letters on framebuffer with raspberry

Tags: bitmap

Is it possible to draw characters, eg letters, on the framebuffer either via ASCII values or as a composition of other lines? a possible implementation as a composition of other graphics primitives makes the code long enough but I find it's the only way to take advantage of the framebuffer.
not having a default function for the letters in the raspberry operating system, how can I take advantage of the ASCII characters to show them on the monitor via hdmi?

Comment: The language used is Forth